# Why does L & L Energy continue to trade OTC even though it's been defunct for years and its former CEO is in jail?

Tags: stocks, scams, china, washington

[L & L Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%26L_Energy) (LLEN) continues to trade OTC even though the company closed.  The former CEO, Dickson Lee, is in jail for securities fraud.  Why does LLEN linger on OTC year after year?  Can stock come back to life?

Comment: It is just as legitimate as any other OTC company?

Comment: A publicly traded company shell is itself an asset.  See   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_takeover  This answers "can stock come back to life" (yes in general) but it would be speculation if that is the end game for the specific LLEN example

Comment: Thank you 662852.  At what point does the OTC stock just go away?  How would one learn if there is Reverse Takeover interest?

Answer (score 2):

The OTC Pink (formerly Pink Sheets) is one of the least regulated.  The bar for maintaining a listing is very low.  If the brokers are still quoting prices to buy or sell the stock then they will continue to trade on the Pink Sheets.

From the [OTC Markets FAQ](https://www.otcmarkets.com/learn/faqs):

> **Can companies get "delisted" from the OTCQX, OTCQB and Pink markets?**
>
> Companies that no longer meet the requirements, or request to be removed, will be removed from OTCQX and OTCQB. Generally, those securities will begin trading on the Pink market. The only way to remove a company from the Pink market is for all of the broker-dealers to stop quoting it. Companies are required to contact FINRA Operations if their securities no longer exist, but are still being quoted. FINRA will investigate and, if appropriate, eliminate the trading symbol and inform OTC Markets Group that they have done so. OTC Markets Group will then remove the quotations in this security.